# "What clues was..." or "What clues were..."?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> The detective, Joe, tells the girl that the scene was covered with clues.
>   The girl can't spot any and thinks, *What clues **[was/were]** Joe talking about?*

Which is right, "was" or "were"?
I've thought "were" since "clues" is plural; but, spellcheck marks it as an error.

Comment: The subject of the verb _to talk_ here is "Joe," not "clues." The correct form of the verb is _was,_ not _were._ It may be easier to understand if you parse it as a declarative: _Joe **was** talking about what clues._

Answer (score 2):

Was refers to Joe, not clues.  Turn the question into a statement and it gets clearer.

Joe was talking about clues.  What clues was Joe talking about?